failed to create query: Field 'vector_field' is not knn_vector type
I am using Aws Bedrock + langchain +openSerach Vector store.
when i ask question to RAG base chatbot it gives me error like "failed to create query: Field 'vector_field' is not knn_vector type."
Is ther any problem with indexing we crating or I need to pass some other paramter in langchain conversational chain.
using following json
{
  "settings": {
    "index": {
      "knn": true,
      "knn.algo_param.ef_search": 100
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "my_vector1": {
        "type": "knn_vector",
        "dimension": 1536,
        "method": {
          "name": "hnsw",
          "space_type": "l2",
          "engine": "faiss",
          "parameters": {
            "ef_construction": 128,
            "m": 24
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

simply using conversationchain of langchain and passing retriver as openserachvectorstore.

There are two ways of fixing it. First is to use "vector_field" instead of "my_vector1":
{
  "settings": {
    "index": {
      "knn": true,
      "knn.algo_param.ef_search": 100
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "vector_field": {
        "type": "knn_vector",
        "dimension": 1536,
        "method": {
          "name": "hnsw",
          "space_type": "l2",
          "engine": "faiss",
          "parameters": {
            "ef_construction": 128,
            "m": 24
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

or you could try
docs = docsearch.similarity_search(
    "What is feature selection",
    k=200,
    vector_field="my_vector1"
)


thanks,
relevant_documents = vectorstore.similarity_search_with_score(query, k=k, search_type = "approximate_search", vector_field="bedrock-knowledge-base-vector1", text_field="MetadataTextFromAOSS")
this worked for me
